# Science fiction short story, where spectators in an arena are called down to the field and killed

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for a short story that takes place in some form of arena, what happens is that there are players on the field of the arena who call down audience members and then kill them on the field one by one. I have been searching for this for a long time and wanted to know if anyone had heard of it.

Comment: What year did you read it?

Comment: Could it be that the players don't actually kill the spectators but rather use their lives to gamble with? The losing player loses his bet and therefore the audience members that volunteer to be his bet gets killed? If so it sounds like an Iain Banks novel. Can't remember the name though.

Comment: @slebetman "Consider Phlebas" is the name of the novel, the first one in the Culture universe.